# Data inserted from excel sheet into mysql is not displayed on JSP

Tags: java, mysql

I have uploaded Excel sheet data (office 2007 version) and it is correctly inserted in MYSQL. When I am fetching it on JSP page it is not displayed and I didn't get any error. While data before uploading excel sheet is properly displayed. And when I delete those data coming from Excel sheet, then it is again OK.

How to overcome this problem?

Comment: Please, provide some code examples.

Comment: can you check if u have committed ur transaction before fetching.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that via Excel you put text in wrong encoding in MySQL. Then Java would throw an Exception if a byte sequence is illegal. This can be the case if Java expects UTF-8, or the database field contains Excel with UTF-16 (byte pairs). To diagnose this, upload an Excel with pure ASCII. If you see that, UTF-8 is guilty.

To repair, ensure that the database/table/field is UTF-8.